# Sharing event with WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, events

I would like to share the event 'MyEvent' in the following class:

```
[ServiceContract]    
    public interface MyInterface
    {

     [OperationContract]
     void Start(); 

     event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;
    }

    public class MyEventArgs:EventArgs
    {
      public string Name{set;get;}
    }
```

Which Attribute should I add to MyEvent event and to the MyEventArgs class and its members?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You can't use events over WCF. To notify clients you should use contract callbacks, or some kind of polling.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/EventDrivenComFoundation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Events are not the way to communicate back to the client in WCF. In WCF you use callbacks. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx#S2 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.callbackcontract.aspx for more information.